# can the past tense of 来る be written in kanji？

Tags: kanji

can きた be written in kanji like this 来た?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%9D%A5%E3%82%8B#Conjugation -> click "show▼"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the result would be 来た。  The same can be said of other kanji as well, hiragana was in part developed so that you can conjugate verbs and still use the kanji.

to come 来る can be conjugated using the kanji as follows:

> 来｛く｝る
>
> 来｛き｝た
>
> 来｛こ｝ない
>
> 来｛こ｝なかった
>
> 来｛こ｝い (imperative command--very direct)

another example: to run (走る）

> そこへ走る。
>
> そこへ走った。
>
> そこへ走らない。
>
> そこへ走らなかった。

As you can see, the hiragana is where the conjugation magic happens, and the kanji is left untouched.  If you're ever in doubt, you can at least be safe in assuming that you would use the kanji regardless.

Answer (score 1):

I understood your question as to whether or not きた can be written using the Kanji despite the change in pronunciation from く in くる to き. The answer is yes, and conjugation is done by mainly changing the Hiragana ending of the verb, but in some cases this also changes how the Kanji is pronunced. Here the pronunciations of the Kanji in question: http://jisho.org/search/%E6%9D%A5

So for a few conjugations of 来る：
来{く}る
来{き}ます
来{こ}ない